# How to make a launcher

Tags: android, launcher

I have been developing for quite a time and I am now trying to make an app that will replace the original home (e.g. HTC sense).

I need the app to open when the the user hits the home button on their phone.

So basically it is a home replacement.

Does any one know how to go about this?

Comment: You can checkout the source code of the [Launcher](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher) and the [Launcher2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2) project used in Android.

Comment: When I hear the word *launcher*, I think of the button that opens the app. Is this what you are referring to? If not, could you provide a link to what you mean - such as to *Wikipedia*?

Comment: Yes, with Launcher I mean - an initial GUI, which loads when the android phone starts (we have standard launcher from Google, TouchWiz at Samsungu, or custom launcher like Launcher Pro and others)

Comment: Here's the source code of `Launcher3` (the AOSP launcher) used in KitKat (and probably lollipop too): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/master If you see any new launcher from AOSP, just replace `3` in the url with the newer version.

Answer (score 106):

Just develop a normal app and then add a couple of lines to the app's manifest file.

First you need to add the following attribute to your activity:

```
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Then add two categories to the intent filter :

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

The result could look something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.dummy.app"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.dummy.app.MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

It's that simple!

Comment: How its activity's lifecycle work? Does it just run indefinitely?

Answer (score 16):

They're examples provided by the Android team, if you've already loaded Samples, you can import **Home screen replacement sample** by following these steps.

> File > New > Other >Android > Android Sample Project > Android x.x >
>   Home > Finish

But if you do not have samples loaded, then download it using the below steps

> Windows > Android SDK Manager > chooses "Sample for SDK" for SDK you
>   need it > Install package > Accept License > Install

Answer (score 12):

*I saw this thread a while ago, before creating my own launcher. 
 Here are some crucial things I learned:*

---

### Declaring your app to be a launcher

David already mentioned the piece of code that determines your app as a launcher:

```xml
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Add this as an [`intent-filter`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element) to the activity your launcher will use for the home screen (in `AndroidManifest.xml`).

### Launcher Issues

As a launcher will run all the time, you need to [understand the activity livecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) to prevent issues ([like this one](https://github.com/finnmglas/Launcher/issues/9)).

If you want users (and yourself) to be able to constantly user the app (that's what you usually do with launchers), **make sure it never crashes.** In the case of a crash users will be taken back to the devices default launcher or other installed ones.

**In short:** Launchers are expected to be reliable.

### Common launcher functions (users usually expect those)

#### 1) A *list of apps / appdrawer*

From which all apps can be launched or modified. You can use [`packageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager?hl=en) to list the apps.

As generating such a list may take a while, I suggest you to do it asynchronously and save the list somewhere to speed everything up (which also is expected from launchers ^^)

#### 2) Some *settings to change the launcher*

I had some users stuck in my launcher before implementing those ^^

You can open the devices launcher settings like this (in Kotlin):

```kotlin
// working in APIs newer than Lollipop
val callHomeSettingIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_HOME_SETTINGS)
startActivity(callHomeSettingIntent)
```

#### Bonus) An in-app tutorial

This may be useful if you have some features in your app that are not trivial, ways of launching apps that users don't know from other apps.

It also gets you way less messages from users asking how to interact with your software.

---

**Resources:**

- The GitHub of the minimal launcher I created may be helpful: [finnmglas/Launcher](https://github.com/finnmglas/Launcher)

Answer (score 10):

Well, firstly you need to listen to the [`android.intent.category.HOME`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HOME) intent. Here are some links with full source code which you can have a look at:

- [Old launcher source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git)
- [New launcher source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git)

Or take a look at [launcher plus](http://code.google.com/p/android-launcher-plus/).