# How to increase icons size on Android Home Screen?

Tags: android, homescreen

I am trying to make changes to default Android Home Screen (like changing cell dimensions, number of elements per row etc) and wondering if there any way I can change apps icon sizes placed on the home screen?

I know that platform takes care of picking up the right dimension image from ldpi (36x36), mdpi (48x48) or hdpi (72x72) directory based on the screen density, but I would like to know if there is any way to increase the icon sizes when application icons are put on the Home Screen irrespective of the screen density?

Comment: Are you developing a custom home screen?  Or just trying to configure your phone?

Comment: There is definitely a way to do it. I'm not sure how it is done though. Check out 'Launcher Pro' on the Market it allows you to change the number of rows and columns of icons, which results in them being bigger or smaller.

Comment: put images, what you have and what you need

Answer (score 2):

Unless you write your own Homescreen launcher or use an existing one from Goolge Play, there's "no way" to resize icons.

Well, "no way" does not mean its impossible:

- As said, you can write [your own launcher as discussed in Stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher)
- You can resize elements on the home screen, but these elements are [AppWidgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html). Since API level 14 they can be resized and user can - in limits - change the size. But that are Widgets not Shortcuts for launching icons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change settings in the launcher, change icon size, or grid size just hold down on an empty part of your home screen. Tap the three Dots and there you go.

From 
https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/how-to-change-icon-and-grid-size-trebuchet-settings.84820/

When configuring the phone for first time I saw something about a grid somewhere, but couldn't find it again. Luckily I found the answer on the link above.