# Override Android home button in Device Admin App

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I override the ‘Home’ button in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547818/can-i-override-the-home-button-in-my-application)

I am creating a device admin application in which I need to disable the home button.
I am successfully able to create a device admin application but I am unable to disable the home button. I have seen many application on Android market which does this even on Android ICS. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547818/can-i-override-the-home-button-in-my-application