# How to relaunch the application which is exited by home button press in android?

Tags: android, event-handling, android-homebutton

I have an android application in which i want to exit the application only on device back key press.I mean that if user clicks on HOME button, I want to exit from the app but relaunch the app after a specific time. How to achieve this?

Comment: when you press home button the application goes to the backgrond not exits. (excpet special cases). What do you exactly want

Comment: I wan to make if my application goes to background on HOME button click, make the app forward.ie,I want to make the application exit only on BACK button click.

Comment: @Devu :still its not clear ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the application to be relaunched you can start a service and in that service you can start your activity using the code :

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

You can set a flag when the home key is pressed and can check in service to ensure that the application is in background, so that activity is not relaunched unnecessarily.

This link might be helpful to you : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547818/can-i-override-the-home-button-in-my-application)