# How to handle home button click event in custom lock screen application

Tags: android, android-activity, homescreen, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I am working in a project where custom lock screen must be implemented once the user clicks the lock button. After clicking, the application should be locked and should also prevent from closing the app while pressing home button. I used [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8576436) to disable home key pressed state:

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow(){ 
        Log.i("TESTE", "onAttachedToWindow");
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
        super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        Log.i("TESTE", "BOTAO HOME");
        return true;
    }
```

The problem with above method is not working for latest versions. So it would be very much helpful if you mentor me by any alternative solutions to achieve this task. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can not override the home key button.

Comment: is there any alternative way to achieve this like how all the app lock application does