# Listen for Home button press

Tags: android, android-homebutton

Is there a way to listen for the user pressing the Home button?

I wanted to override the Home button functionality, but I have read in many places that "For security reasons we can't override home button". Can we override the Home button, or not?

I have tried with various code snippets. One sample I took from the below site:

- http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/06/02/override-hardware-home-button-android-listen-home-button-click-android/

I tested it in Latest Samsung J8 Phone but it did not work.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547818/can-i-override-the-home-button-in-my-application

Comment: @Siva you cannot override Home button simply. The way to do it is to create a "Launcher App", which is relatively complex and requires special steps from the user to install properly. And that linked code is never going to work - I think it may have worked in 2012 when written, but the functionality has long since been removed.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is can we override home button or Can't?

Answer: since android 4.0, you can not override home button as a non-system app.

But there are some ways to listen whether users have pressed home button. If you are interested in this, I would supply some solutions for you.

---

Edit： Add some solutions to listen home button pressed.

I supply you two ways to listen home button pressed event.
First, reigster a Broadcast Receiver.

```
class HomeKeyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
      //press Home button
      final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";
      //press recent app button
      final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";
      // long press home button
      final String SYSTEM_DIALOGS_REASON_LONG_PRESS_HOME_KEY = "globalactions";
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          String action = intent.getAction();
          if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
              String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
              if (reason != null) {
                  if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                      //  press home , do something

                  } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {
                      //  press recent app , do something

                  } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOGS_REASON_LONG_PRESS_HOME_KEY)) {
                      //  long press home button , do something
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

  // register Receiver
  AppUtils.context.registerReceiver(homeKeyBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
```

Another way, you can register lifecycle callback in your application.

```
application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new HomeButtonListerLifecycleCallbacks());

  public class HomeButtonListerLifecycleCallbacks implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
      // check threshold
      private final int CHECK_DELAY = 200;

      private Handler handler;
      private Runnable checkRunnable;

      public HomeButtonListerLifecycleCallbacks() {
          this.handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          ZZLocalPushInfoManager.getInstance().onCreateActivity(activity);
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
          if (handler != null && checkRunnable != null) {
              handler.removeCallbacks(checkRunnable);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityPaused(final Activity activity) {
          if (handler != null) {
              if (checkRunnable != null) {
                  handler.removeCallbacks(checkRunnable);
              }
              handler.postDelayed(checkRunnable = new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      // Here user has left your app. mostly they pressed home button,
                      // but they also can go to other app by notification,etc.
                  }
              }, CHECK_DELAY);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

      }
  }
```

Comment: Yes please suggest

Comment: That first block of code is a great trick that you've just taught me - thanks! It does not _override_ but does _listen_ at least.
The second block does not say "how" the user left the app (i.e. HOME vs BACK) - it merely says that the user "did leave" the app.