# Android custom launcher/ home replacement development

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen

I am trying to develop an android custom launcher like ADW launcher.

So, have been searching for some good information.

Most of the questions/answers found in google and Stackoverflow are about how to make an application work as a launcher. But I want to know how I should actually start developing a Custom launcher.

Can anyone please guide me the fundamental steps and resources to develop a Custom launcher.

Comment: Questions not _directly_ relating to code are off-topic on Stack Overflow. I think Google would be the best place to find an answer.

Comment: Try learning from already existing Launcher code like ADW (which is open source).

Comment: Thanks, JoxTraex, am working on it.

Comment: @RyanCarlson, I happen to get a partial answer here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918900/understanding-custom-android-launcher?rq=1

Downvoters, cant understand how the above given link got such votes though.

Comment: @Sam I really have no clue how that question survived. Personally, I think this question is far better than that one.

Comment: @JoxTraex ...I happen to get a partial answer here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918900/understanding-custom-android-launcher?rq=1

Cant understand how the above given link got such votes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you out, assuming you can code java.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2583692

Comment: Thank u Aashir, I will try out the tutorial.
BTW, I can code Java :)

Comment: Thanks again @Aashir , I checked out the video, and honestly, U really helped me save the frustrations and time.

Sorry, I would vote up ur answer, if I could.

Comment: So long as it helped you, I'm happy.