# android: choose default launcher programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, homescreen, android-launcher

I want to pop up a dialog that lets the user choose a launcher to be launched **with set as default option**. I tried

```
Intent home = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
home.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(home, "Launcher");
context.startActivity(chooser);
```

But the dialog popped by this does not have the option to set default. While the following code will not pop up the dialog if a default launcher is already set.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

If a default action is already set (**yours**),  you can call first:

```
getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());
```

If the default action is not yours, you cannot clear it programmatically, what you can do is to check if other app is set as default and show a message..

```
private boolean isMyLauncherDefault() {
    PackageManager localPackageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    String str = localPackageManager.resolveActivity(intent,
          PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).activityInfo.packageName;
    return str.equals(getPackageName());
}
```

As a workaround in case of other app is set as default, you can created a `fake` home, install it (this will force the system to clear the default app) and then uninstall it...

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name="FakeHome"  android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**FakeHome.java**

```
public class FakeHome extends Activity {

}
```

**Somewhere**

```
if (!isMyLauncherDefault()) {           
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName cN = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), FakeHome.class);
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);            
    startActivity(selector);

    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);            
}
```

Comment: This code will not pop up the dialog if a default launcher is already set.

Comment: The `filters` parameter of `getPreferredActivities()` is an output parameter. Adding a filter item to the list before the call has no effect.

Comment: @Nermeen where this isMyLauncherDefault() is called?FakeHome Activity or any other activity? and where to pass the above intent?

Comment: This works well. Is there any way to make this work using ROLE_HOME ?

Answer (score 5):

Starting from API 29 this is now officially supported using [RoleManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/role/RoleManager.html).

A very simple Kotlin example of a method you can call from any activity:

```
fun showLauncherSelector(activity: AppCompatActivity, requestCode : Int) {
    val roleManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.ROLE_SERVICE) as RoleManager
    if(roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_HOME)){
        val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.ROLE_HOME)
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
    }
}
```

Then you can check for errors in the caller activity:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Something went wrong
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I simply do not understand why they have created `Kotlin`, just to make similar answers useless.

Comment: Sadly this works only if you have an enabled Activity that can handle the Intent. If not, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
```