# Default Launcher App - How to detect if another app is 'always' the launcher

Tags: android

When another app is selected as 'always' the default launcher, when I try to startup launcher dialog it just goes directly to the 'always' selected launcher.  So how can I detect if another app is 'always' the launcher?

[android: choose default launcher programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110047/android-choose-default-launcher-programatically)

Is a solution, but the problem is if the user has already selected another app 'always' firing off this intent just goes to the home screen, and not a selector dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try resolving the intent yourself via PackageMangers `resolveActivity (Intent intent, int flags)` ?

You have to configure the intent for launching the default launcher and then determine from that result if you can detect another launcher.