# Set Default SMS App in android Without startActivity

Tags: android

Is it Possible to set Default SMS application back to Messaging app in background or without using this code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                        intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110047/android-choose-default-launcher-programatically

Answer (score 2):

No, the reason the Intent exists is so that the user has the final option of choosing their default SMS app.

Comment: You mean there is only one option to set default messing app from settings? user has to change from settings only we can not do it programmatically Without user confirmation ?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of a user chosen default app.