# How to show default launcher chooser?

Tags: android, android-launcher

i'm creating a launcher app and i would like to show the default launcher chooser manually.

I already found and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991656/how-to-set-default-app-launcher-programmatically) but this is not perfect, since i cannot select ALWAYS immediately. After choosing the launcher i need to press the home button to be able to select ALWAYS.

This is my code:

```
public static void resetPreferredLauncherAndOpenChooser(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, DefaultLauncherHelperActivity.class);
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    selector.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(selector);

    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

and here the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity
        android:name=".activities.DefaultLauncherHelperActivity"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is what i get (left) vs. what i'm trying to achieve (right)

[image]

There has to be a way since Microsoft's launcher and the poco launcher are able to do this but i couldn't find a solution and unfortunately there is no open source launcher with the same functionality. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110047/android-choose-default-launcher-programmatically

Comment: This is the same i'm already doing but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward API available for this. However, calling below code before resetting preferred launcher will result in chooser dialog as per right side image.

**Use it cautiously** as calling this will actually resets user home app  preference and effect can be seen outside of your home app as well.

```
try {
      IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
      intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
      intentFilter.addCategory(CATEGORY_HOME);
      intentFilter.addCategory(CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
      Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
      intent1.addCategory(CATEGORY_HOME);
      intent1.setComponent(null);
      Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("android.app.AppGlobals");
      Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageManager")
           .getMethod("setLastChosenActivity", new Class[] { Intent.class, String.class, int.class, IntentFilter.class, int.class, ComponentName.class })
                .invoke(clazz.getMethod("getPackageManager", new Class[0]).invoke(clazz, null),
                    new Object[] { intent1, intent1.resolveTypeIfNeeded(context.getContentResolver()), Integer.valueOf(65536), intentFilter, Integer.valueOf(1081344), intent1.getComponent() });
} catch (Exception ignore) {
}
```