# flutter: choose launcher as default programmatically

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-intent, android-launcher

I am developing a launcher app and want the user to get a pop up where they can choose my app as their default launcher, I have seen quite a few questions on stack overflow for the same, but they were for android. I am assuming that the only way to do this is with using intents so I tried using this [intent package](https://pub.dev/packages/intent), I tried simulating the code here, [android: choose default launcher programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110047/android-choose-default-launcher-programmatically), but wasn't able to successfully complete it. Is there a way to do it in Flutter? Anyway, here is my code from what I tried:

```
// method is called in initState()
void defaultLauncherOption() {
    intentFlutter
        .Intent()
          ..setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN")
          ..addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME")
          ..addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
          ..addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
          ..startActivity().catchError((e) => print("intent error: " + e.toString()));
  }

// the code doesn't give any errors but is not performing any operation as well.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone needs the answer to this question, I did it using the [intent package](https://pub.dev/packages/intent) and by the following code:

```
void displayDefaultLauncherChooser() {
    intentFlutter
        .Intent()
          ..setAction(actionFlutter.Action.ACTION_MAIN)
          ..addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME")
          ..addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
          ..addFlag(flag.Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT)
          ..startActivity().catchError((e) => print("intent error: " + e.toString()));
  }
```