# How to make flutter application a default home launcher in android

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity, android-launcher

I want to make my flutter app default home launcher, i have added category Home and Default inside intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml.

Now i when i press home button in my android i am not getting popup to choose from default home launcher.
How to get the popup where a user can choose to make it a default home launcher.

Following the artile on [Make Your Own Custom Android Launcher using Flutter](https://dev.to/mh_shifat/make-your-own-custom-android-launcher-using-flutter-558j)  i have added the below code to my AndroidManifest.xml

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

I am not getting any prompt/popup to use Launcher as home.

Please Help

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am running into the same problem...

Comment: I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23110115/13129435) which helped me, you can check it out it works

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not being able to solve this, the issue could be related to OS settings.

I do not guarantee this solution, but it worked for me. Simple goto settings and choose default apps. Then choose your app for launcher as a default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35487634)