# how to make a simple launcher in android?

Tags: java, android, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher)

I want to make a launcher something similar to go launcher which changes all the icons and stuff... Currently I wanna know where should I start from? I need to make a very simple launcher so any sample code will be appreciated. Thanks!
Any helpful codes I should know or any tips?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Launcher sample app included in the SDK samples that has some simple launcher code that you could base your app on. I doubt there's any simpler code available than that one.

Comment: u mean "home" in /samples/android-10?

Comment: Yes, that would be the one