# Create a shortcut button with icon and name like samsung's clock app

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, shortcut

I want to make a Button or ImageView or something like that to launch an app. At some point i want to make several to keep adding shortcuts like the Samsung desk clock [app](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21682671/Untitled-1.png).

At the moment ive set up some blank Button's in which i want to be able to click, choose the app i want then the app create the icon and name to the button (like above) and it launch the intent when i click it afterwards.

Any ideas, examples etc are brilliant ive got brain ache searching for a way to do this :/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7107138/1337412

You're basically trying to create a custom "launcher app" if you search StackOverflow and Google, you should be able to find plenty of examples of launcher apps.

Comment: Well no not really. I'm making a desk clock where at the bottom the user can create shortcuts to apps. I know it's something to do with PackageManager but it's how to put the icon and name and then be able to launch the app via that

Comment: I know it's not actually a launcher, but the way you launch apps and get their icon will be the same as a launcher.