# How can my Launcher deploy default launcher choice window?

Tags: android, launcher

I had an android launcher project. After installed on my phone, pressing HOME will NOT make the "default launcher choise" popwindow showing to choose default launcher.

following is related setting:

```
        <activity
          android:name="MyLauncherActivity"
            .....
            .....
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

how can I make that popupWindow show ?

P.S  How curiouse it is! I just restart Eclipse and reinstall it, pressing HOME make the default launcher choise popupwindow showing!

Answer (score 0):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

in your activity intent-filter means this is the start point of the app, when the user clicks on the app icon, will run this activity ( it **doesn't** mean this activity is a launcher app)

and you are looking for this:

[How to make a launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher)

Comment: my code works as an launcher. I just do not know why it did NOT work before. just restarting my Eclipse, it work! Curiouse!