# Setting an app as launcher?

Tags: java, android, launcher

I was wondering how I can set up an app as launcher? 
Is making a launcher any different than making an app? What permissions do I have?

Thank you, and please excuse me if I'm not asking the correct format, I'm relatively new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same questions, essentially:

[How to make a launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher)

However, replacing a launcher is more complex than the example, as discussed in this blog / example:

http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/

And a launcher app is "just an app" but if it's a great "app" it's much more complex than it appears. Customization and options add a lot of code to a great app.