# How to start automatically an application when Google glass start?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I would like to know how to start **automatically** a specific Glassware once my glasses are turned on ?

What would be the best way to do that?

PS: that would be for a user that use Google glass only this specific glassware and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Glass is an Android devices. It behaves just like an Android device.

You can start an application on boot just like how we do it on normal Android devices.

[How to start an Application on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391902/how-to-start-an-application-on-startup)

Or you can make a `launcher` application and disable the `launcher` on the Glass. Then the default clock screen won't appear at all on the glass. Only your glassware will be launched and use cannot navigate from it.

[How to make a launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher)