# Hide softkeys on my android app

Tags: android, softkeys

In my app I want to remove completly the softkeys (back, home, etc).
I've managed to do that with:

```
getWindow ( ).getDecorView ( ).setSystemUiVisibility ( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION );
```

But when I touch the screen it comes back, and does not go away...
I also have `"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` on manifest and

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Does not help...

Anyone knows how to get over this?

Thanks.

Comment: how does a user leave your application?

Comment: The app should "auto-run" in startup and the user should not be able to get to android system. It's suppose to have a hidden button to exit to android, for service if needed.

Comment: then your app should be a launcher, not a simple app. (Still requires the user to declare it as default launcher, but only once.) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher

Comment: Thanks, I did not thought of that way... Can I hide the softkeys that way also?

Comment: no. But when a User would press home, they would get back to your home page.

Comment: And if I really want to remove the soft-key bar? I need it's space on the display...

Comment: only on kitkat: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html