# My android application always be in launcher list

Tags: android

hi i am new in android application Development

after successfully Developed android application when i install apk of that application it is always under launcher list, and always ask to select default launcher when i press Home key. How to prevent app. to be in list under launcher.

manifest file code are as follow.

```
//Manifest
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.dewebclient.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.dewebclient.IpConfigure" ></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.dewebclient.WebViewClientDE"  />
      <!--android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"-->
</application>
```

Comment: Remove <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> this line.

Comment: Then I add this as a answer please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Remove above line from **AndroidManifest.xml** .

Answer (score 1):

Remove below line from your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />`

**Explanation :**

The category **HOME** is used to declare your application as a Home launcher. By putting this in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, user will have the option to have your application open upon pressing the home button.

> **According to Developer Docs.** 
>   This is the home activity, that is the first activity that is displayed when the device boots.

Answer (score 0):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
```

Remove this and check.

This indicates that when you press home button, your app will be listed as an option to launch the launcher home or your home activity (along with all the applications which have this category in their manifest for an activity). To be more simple, whenever you press the home button, all the applications installed in your phone which have CATEGORY.HOME category and Action_Main in intent-filter in their AndroidManifest.xml will be listed (unless you have chosen some application as default) in a chooser for the user to select which HOME they want to launch.

Comment: Thank you very much Nice Explanation. With Right Answer.

Answer (score 0):

change your intent filter look like below.
and relaunch application.

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

referenc this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22126720/3513479)