# Framework7 Single App Mode

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

Is there any possibility to prevent user from closing the app in Framework7? Let's say I have an app that should work kinda like Kioskmode.

Thank you

Comment: is for an Android platform ?

Comment: Yes, it's android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android it's really simple : Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher#answer-22126720), you have just few lines to add in manifest file.

Also, there is [this cordova project](https://github.com/Aricwithana/DOMLauncher2) that you can explore !